# Rails: How to use select in formtastic with activeRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, formtastic

I'm new to rails and I guess you can answer this question easily.

What I got so far is

```
= f.input :task, :as => :select, :collection => @tasks, :include_blank => true
```

where the tasks collection is defined by

```
Task.find(:all)
```

within in the controller.

This does in fact work, shows me a dropdown-list of all Tasks to select from and connects them.
The problem here is, that the dropdown menu shows me values like

```
#<Task:0x123456789d1234>
```

Where do I define what value is being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use the `:label_method` to solve your problem...

```
f.input :task, :as => :select, :collection => @tasks, 
   :include_blank => true, :label_method => :title
```

where `:title` is what you want to show.

[`This`](http://groups.google.com.au/group/formtastic/browse_thread/thread/4d6c1f21500d44cf) may help a little more.

Comment: thank you very mouch, the link you posted worked great.
Just had to implement a "to_label" function within the model class

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `to_s` method in the model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_s
    title # the attribute to display for the label
  end

end
```